# Capturing Application Audio for Manipulation and Streaming

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-streaming, naudio, windows-core-audio

I am working on an application in Unity which needs to be able to do the following:

- get the audio data from the active applications on the local machine
- filter out audio so that only specific audio data is left
- combine the remaining audio data into a memory stream or something that can be shipped across the network in real time

Basically I have the video of an application streaming but there is no audio for the third party I am using so I need to implement that. I'm looking for something like discord has where viewers of the stream can hear the audio for the application you're streaming to them.

I have researched WASAPI quite a bit and I have been able to get information on the applications that have active audio sessions...but I can't get the audio data itself. The same goes for NAudio since it uses WASAPI. Apparently, I can use the Windows Core Audio APIs but I haven't seen what in that API does what I'm asking for.

Does anyone have any tips on where I should be looking next?